# Copying speed to external hard drive get slower and slower

Tags: usb, files, transfer

When I copy files (lots of them) to an external hard drive it's start on a pretty good speed and get slower and slower until I just give up.

Comment: look here...it's arch, but still Linux so.... https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=182859

Comment: What results from hdparm -t on the device (three times)?  Any errors in the syslog on the USB?  Tried a different port?  USB2 or USB3?  What are you using to copy (cp, tar, rsync,...)?  What file system is on the USB (is it journaling?)?

Answer (score 0):

Of cause it depends on your connection like USB2/USB3 and the internal and external disk speed. But try to use rsync:

`rsync -arzv --progress /folder/source/* /folder/destination/`

What connection do you have? 
What speed can you report?

---

```
rsync - a fast, versatile, remote (and local) file-copying tool
 -a, --archive               archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)
 -r, --recursive             recurse into directories
 -z, --compress              compress file data during the transfer
 -v, --verbose               increase verbosity
     --progress              show progress during transfer
```

Depending on the processor it might make sense not to use the parameter *-z*